# How can i change property in InstallScript

Tags: installshield

I want to change property value to selected text in a dialog.

this is my sample source.

```
#include "ifx.h"
STRING outPath;
export prototype MyFunction(HWND);

function OnFirstUIBefore()
    NUMBER nResult, nSetupType, nvSize, nUser;
    STRING szTitle, szMsg, szQuestion, svName, svCompany, szFile, szDir;
    STRING szLicenseFile;
    BOOL bCustom, bIgnore1, bIgnore2;
begin   

Dlg_SdAskDestPath:      
    nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, szMsg, INSTALLDIR, 0);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdAskDestPath;

Dlg_AskOutPath:     
    nResult = AskDestPath(szTitle, szmsg, szDir, 0);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdAskDestPath;
    outPath = szDir;
    MyFunction(ISMSI_HANDLE);

return 0;
end;

function MyFunction(hMSI)
    STRING value;
begin
    MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "OutPutPath", outPath);
end;
```

OutPutPath used in custom action after finish install.

But OutPutPath was not changed when read in custom action.

I think I must not use ISMSI_HANDLE. But i don't know what i have to use instead.

I tried to make custom action which load Install scripts's method MyFunction after finish install.

It worked well, But the global variable outPath was nul..

Please teach me how can i do this if you know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you must use a [public property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912), that is one with a name that does not contain any lowercase letters. You may also have to list it in [SecureCustomProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371571) in order to allow users to modify it, if you support installation in restricted environments.

However I'm not certain the exact scenario described by your comment:

> I tried to make custom action which load Install scripts's method MyFunction after finish install.

If this scenario is truly after the end of the Windows Installer portion of the installation (an InstallScript MSI runs code both before and after), properties as a whole may not survive to do what you need. To support reading the value at that time you will have to consider other approaches, such as writing the value in the registry, or into a file (e.g. in SUPPORTDIR).